# SOLR get a negative of the filter list / exclude fields from filter list

Tags: indexing, solr

I am looking for the way to create a query to SOLR with a specified fl (filter list) parameters. I would like that SOLR send me all fields except those received into the request.

Is there some way to make negation like :

```
fl=not NAME
```

I saw the bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3191 opened but is there any solution ?

Thanks

Comment: Just looked at the [source code](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/search/SolrReturnFields.java) for the `fl` parameter - doesn't look like there is a way to exclude. Happy to be wrong though.

Comment: Since the issue is still open I think you can safely assume that this is still not possible. If you _really_ want to, there's a patch on the issue that you can apply and help test the feature yourself.